# Can you help me create a method that will return an entire Linked list and Queue-array;

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

As of now this is the method I have for my Queue,

```
public String rQueue()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < queueName.length; i++)
    return queueName[i];
 return

" ";
}
```

The problem here is that the `i++` is never reached because the `queueName[i]` is returned, when I use this method, only the first one is returned, and I can see why. How can I fix it so that I can return the entire contents of the queue.

I am also confused on the linked list, I have a linked list of an `Object()`. I only want to return `Object.getMethod();` for every instance of each link. So this is what I have. The only way I can think of doing it is with another loop and to look at each spot, but I don't know how to return something like that.

```
 public String displayLink()
{
      Link current = first;
      while(current != null)
      {
          current.displayMethod();
          current = current.next;
      }
}
```

I am really more stuck on the linked list, and the queue is just sort of a technical problem.

Comment: Just return the queue?  'public queue* rQueue();' ?  Sorry!  Wrong language..

Comment: I am also having same problem and for that i am referring this link--
<a href="http://niravsai.blogspot.in/2012/06/program-to-maintain-singly-linked-list.html" title="example">Click Here</a>
I think that is useful to you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a concatenation you could do something like:

```
public String rQueue() {
  String r = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < queueName.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      r += ", ";
    }
    r += queueName[i];
  }
  return r;
}
```

For the linked list you can return a collection. If *displayMethod* returns *string*, you could do something like:

```
public Collection<String> displayLink() {
      Collection<String> result = new List<String>();
      Link current = first;
      while(current != null) {
          result.add(current.displayMethod());
          current = current.next;
      }
      return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First part,

```
public String[] qQueue { return queueName; } // or defensively copy, if you prefer
```

Then you have the array as the queue contents, if that's how it fits into the rest of your code.

Second part looks just fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with the Linked List is actually the only way to traverse it (assuming it is a simple linked list with links from one node to the next). This is also why retrieving an element from a linked list is an O(n) operation, since you have to traverse the list to find the object you are looking for.
Now as far as returning the values is concerned you can just append them to a String and return this String in the end. Something like this would work:

```
public String rQueue() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < queueName.length; i++)
        sb = sb.append(queueName[i]);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that I am using a StringBuffer in the above code since it is more efficient than concatenating to the end of a String, especially for a large number of concatenations.